# Hiding a tag (ODOO 12)

Tags: xml, odoo-12

i'm working on odoo 12 (python 3.6) and i'm trying to inherit from the product.template and hide the price tag in the kanban box , only hiding the field near to it was possible(lst_price field) , but the tag stay the same i tried this code:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@name='tags']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
```

but it didn't work ..

**this is how it appears in the kanban view code of product.template** 
[image: this is how it appears in the kanban view code of product.template]
***HELP PLEASE***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing different tag, to perform the operation apply on **li** tag like this way,

```
<xpath expr="//ul/li" position="">
    <!-- Perform Your Operation -->
</xpath>
```

On you XPath that div tags are already close.after that have the new tag with **ul** and then **li**.

Thanks